Rokoko retarget messing up Rigify face MCH bones
I have a basic human model (left) which I'm trying to retarget to mixamo animation.

I matched all the bones and aligned the poses

I retarget the animation (I disable Auto Scale and choose Use Pose: Current) and everything works except... the face bones are all over the place

All the other bones follow mixamo rig perfectly fine. Only the MCH-lid_handle, MCH-lid_end_handle, MCH-nose_endreparent, MCH-nose_offset and so on are completely messed up.
Interstingly the MCH-forearm and other libs are stuck in place but they don't seem to have any effects on DEF bones.

The face MCH bones also don't actually deform anything but the nose.L, nose.R, lip.B.L, lip.T.R, etc... do

And they are parented to MCH bones

I tried deleting face bone channels from the animation but the makes 0 difference

Also no difference if I try deleting channels of MCH bones.

